# How do you pronounce the notation for partial regression coefficients?

Tags: multiple-regression, partial-correlation

I've been working through [Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Causal+Inference+in+Statistics%3A+A+Primer-p-9781119186847)
 and have hit a bit of a roadblock in my understanding when on page 24 the authors introduced the following notation for the partial regression coefficient between Z and Y when controlled by X:
$$R_{ZY\cdot X}$$

I feel that my difficulty understanding this concept is at least partially caused by not knowing how to say it out loud and what that dot means. E.g. should I say "R of ZY dot X"?

I've been also looking at the Wikidepia article on [Partial correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation) which uses this notation for some of the examples, but doesn't provide a pronunciation either. But the article does provide a geometrical interpretation section that mentions a zero scalar product between the ZY plane and X, so am I right to assume that the centered dot in this notation is alluding to the dot product?

Comment: That would be a poor assumption.  After all, what would be the arguments of the dot product?  It's almost always a better idea to refer to the author's definitions rather than attempting to relate the symbols to those you might be familiar with.

Comment: Thanks @whuber, yes, that's why I'm asking. It doesn't seem to be explained in the book (or anywhere else I could find) why there's a dot in that notation and I don't recall ever seeing a \cdot anywhere else in statistics, unless directly tied into linear algebra.

Comment: The dot there is just a notation and has nothing to do with the dot product. The wiki article you linked gives the definition you’re looking for.

Comment: Thanks @utobi, but what do you mean "just a notation"? I would assume that whoever defined it had some meaning in mind for that dot, no? I can't recall ever seeing a dot used as just a meaningless separator.